# Retrieve, Resize and Display MySQL BLOB image

Tags: php, mysql, database, blob, image-resizing

Im trying to resize and display an image from my MySQL database.
Im able to display the image but when I try to put it in a table or size it, it shows no image. I attached a screen shot of what I get when I try to add any style to it.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAxRv.png) If I display it with no style it works fine.
Below is the my code.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
//DB details
$dbHost     = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'user';
$dbPassword = 'pswd';
$dbName     = 'db';

//Create connection and select DB
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

//Check connection
if($db->connect_error){
   die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}

//Get image data from database
$result = $db->query("SELECT receipt FROM Expense WHERE id = {$_GET['id']}");

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $imgData = $result->fetch_assoc();

    //Render image
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

      echo "<tr>
      <td>".$imgData['receipt']."</td>
      </tr>";

}else{
    echo 'Image not found...';
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: This looks like pretty old code. You should not be using `mysql_` in PHP, nor `table`s for design in HTML. Use CSS. Additionally your SQL is open to injections.

Comment: What do you mean injections?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php Basically `$_GET['id']` comes from user input and could contain anything, additional SQL functions can be added and users/bots can manipulate your data... or obtain data they shouldnt have access to

Comment: What is `receipt`, a blob or a file location on your server?

Comment: That is temporary for testing

Comment: Yes on receipt. Just a picture image of a receipt

Comment: What is in the database a blob or string that contains the files location?

Comment: Images are stored in the database as BLOB. More specifically LONGBLOB

Comment: Okay, so either base64 encode the return in an `src` of an `img` tag, or make a page that will render the image. You can't use `image/jpeg` with `HTML`. All the bytes would need to compile an image

Comment: It's unusual to store images this way , especially if larger than 100kb, say - as I suspect these are.

Comment: Yes they are. I’m using MySQL database for expense recording with receipt images. What’s another way to store the receipts images but linked to the expense data in the database? I have hosting space with hostgator.

Comment: I rewrote the code. I'm getting I guess binary gibberish on my screen.

<?php

displayImage();

function displayImage()

{

 $connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "", "");
 mysql_select_db("", $connect);
 $qry="SELECT receipt FROM Expense WHERE id = 27";
 $result=mysql_query($qry, $connect);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row['receipt'].'"> ';
 
 }
 mysql_close($connect);
}

?>